# connection limit exceeded for mongo from aws

Tags: reactjs, django, linux, mongodb, amazon-web-services

When I am trying to put requests from AWS cloud9 environment to Mongo DB Atlas, connectivity with MongoDB is slowed down. To add, while putting query on MongoDB, python code is taking time to fetch the data from database and even hanged. Ours is a free tier and I think the concurrent connection limit is 500. The problem arise after 2-3 weeks. Can we buy some connections? Or how to increase the connection limit.

-Amar

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I don't see any reply to my questions. I am elaborating my question. Please notify me about any plan or any way to increase the connection limit or howproblem. to fix out existing problem.